# Why is $13^n\cdot 14 + 13\cdot 2^{2n}$ divisible by $9$ for any nonnegative integer $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Prove that statement

$13^n\cdot14+13\cdot2^{2n}$ is divisible by $9$ for any natural $n$

So, the first step is to represent $13^n$ as sum of

$(9+4)^n$ and what the next one?

Give me a hint, please.

I've no idea where to go for now.

Thanks!

Comment: Expand $(9+4)^n$ by binomial theorem and it $\equiv 4^n \equiv \cdots$ (mod $9$). But usually we just complete the proof by induction. Can you try the latter?

Comment: @Yuki.F No need for binomial theorem. But OP surely doesn't know about modular arithmetic yet.

Comment: Hint: Let $x_n = 13^n\cdot14+13\cdot2^{2n} = 13^n\cdot14+13\cdot4^{n}$. Then $x_{n+2}=(13+4)x_{n+1}-(13\cdot4)x_n$.

Comment: @Zuy how bare modular arithmetic could help here?
I mean with no binominal expansion could you give an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your comments, I gather, you are familiar with modular arithmetic. In that case, the problem becomes quite simple.

Note that $13\equiv 4(\operatorname{mod} 9)$ and $14\equiv 5(\operatorname{mod} 9)$ and so
$$13^n.14+13.2^{2n}\equiv 4^n.5+4.4^n\equiv 4^n.9\equiv 0\;(\operatorname{mod} 9)$$

Comment: Your solution is based on Euler's totient theorem as far as I can see, right?

Comment: @Twissell Not at all. We don't need to reduce the exponents (except for $2^{2n}=4^n$), so no totient function involved.

Comment: no @Twissell, it's just very straightforward modular calculations

Answer (score 2):

Free of modular arithmetics:
$$
13^n\cdot 14+13\cdot 2^{2n}=(13^n-4^n)14+14\cdot 4^n+13\cdot4^n=(13^n-4^n)14+27\cdot 4^n
$$
which is divisible by $9$ because $9|27$ and $9|(13^n-4^n)=9\cdot\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}13^i4^{n-1-i}$.

Answer (score 1):

One can always do it by induction.

$13^{n+1} \cdot 14 + 13\cdot 2^{2(n+1)}=$

$13^n\cdot 14\times 13 + 13\cdot 2^{2n}\times 4=$

$13^n\cdot 14\times(9+4) + 13 \cdot2^{2n}\times 4=$

$13^n\cdot 14\times 9 + 4\times (13^n\cdot 14+ 13 \cdot2^{2n})$

which is a multiple of $9$ if $13^n\cdot 14+ 13 \cdot2^{2n}$ is.